# Why Redux returns old state when dispatch action before?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to know why when I dispatch action before my console log prints old state. 
if I do next:
reducer.js

```
let initialState = { display: false };
const MyReducer = (state = initialState,action) => { 
  ...
  case 'SET_DISPLAY':
    return { update(state,{ display : {$set: action.display } }) }
    break;
  default:
    return state;
  break;
}
```

ActionCreator.js

```
let ActionCreator = {
  setDisplay(value) {
    return(dispatch,getState) {
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_DISPLAY',display: value})
    }
  }
};
```

app.js

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.dispatch(ActionCreator.setDisplay(true))
  // expected : true
  console.log(this.props.display)
  // prints : false.
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  display : state.display
}
```

but I can see changes in my redux dev-tools console.
PD I use redux-thunk as Middleware.its just example,all my code seems good and works great,but,its a question.
Why console logs old state instead a new state (its ilogic, if I dispatched an action before call logs) I will apreciate your answers,thanks.

Comment: Your action creator looks weird, are you sure that is correct? Does the change not happen at all, or does it just not happen in the `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do with a basic (plain object) Action Creator neither works. setDisplay(){ return { type: 'ENABLE_DISPLAY '} } , I cant use conditionals,for example: ComponentDidMount(){ this.props.dispatch({ type: 'ENABLE_DISPLAY'}); if(this.props.display_is_enabled){ // do anything } } because gets old state,but in my redux console I see the correct state (updated) . Console.log doesnt display any error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using redux-thunk and your dispatch happens aynchronously.

this.props.dispatch(ActionCreator.setDisplay(true)) will not set display true immediately.

Since you are not making a network request or anything async in that action why dont you change the action creator to

```
let ActionCreator = {
  setDisplay(value) {
    return { type: 'SET_DISPLAY',display: value};
  }
};
```

Now it will happen synchronously. Also dont put console log immediately after dispatching. As redux  updates state, old state is not modified. Instead it creates a new state instance with updated value. This new value will be passed as props to your component via connect of react-redux. 
Try printing display in render() method, you will see that it is called twice and second one will display true.

Comment: Thanks,but it does not works. 
Component.js
`componentDidMount(){
 this.props.setDisplay(true);
 if(this.props.display === false){
  // its false
 }else{
  // true
 }
}`
My console prints:
**{type: "SET_DISPLAY", display: true}
its false**

Why? in render method console.log says updated store value.

Comment: In React there are lifecycle methods like componentDidMount() componentDidUpdate() render() etc. componentDidMount() will be called during initial mount of the component with props and state passed initially to the component.

Comment: When you are updating redux store in componentDidMount() it is just updating redux store not your components props. React-Redux is listening to any change in state and passing that down to components which wont happen in same thread. so immediately after  dispatch your props will reflect old props itself.

Comment: When new props are passed to component via connect, component re-renders it will execute render() again, but componentDidMount() wont be again executed. this is why render is called twice.

Comment: Really nice answer, very complete,thanks! I completely forgot that.So, what lifecycle method do  you suggest to handle my store state change? (last question,sorry for that.) maybe componentDidUpdate ? componentDidUpdate => () { if(this.props.display) // do anything.. } seems works pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend not to rely on the fact that dispatching an action may be synchronous; design as if everything was asynchronous. When eventually you dispatch an async actions, you will be pleased to have your mindset ready for that.

Second, your action creator return a function (you must be using the thunk middleware), which is why you get this behaviour.

---

```
  componentDidMount(){
   startSomethingAsync();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if (!this.props.asyncCompleted) return;

    if(this.props.asyncResultFn) {
       this.props.dispatch({ type: ... value: VALUE_CONDITIONAL_TRUE}) 
    }
    else{
       this.props.dispatch({ type: ... value: VALUE_CONDITIONAL_FALSE}) 
    }
  }
```

Comment: I already use redux-thunk. Can you put one simple example can solve this? thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks, so.. how I can handle it in my logic component? I need to do in ComponentDidMount,doesnt works to me in render method. I want to do some like this.. `componentDidMount() => this.props.asyncFunction() if(this.props.asyncResultFn) {  this.props.dispatch({ type: ... value: VALUE_CONDITIONAL_TRUE})  }else{ this.props.dispatch({ type: ... value: VALUE_CONDITIONAL_FALSE }) }` sorry, I'm lost.

Comment: "Second, your action creator is in the form of an async action creator (you must be using the thunk middleware), which is why you get this behaviour." - @Sylvain why do you think it's async? Both redux and [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js) are synchronous code and the OP's ActionCreator code is not async either. (Of course React lifecycle events arise asynchronously but you conclude async is present due to the use of the thunk middleware)

Comment: @RobertMonfera because this action creator returns a function that return an action, not a plain action.

Comment: @Sylvain this fact alone doesn't make it async unless there's some `if` condition that if it's a function then it'll do something async, am I missing something? The code I linked just calls the function synchronously: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js#L3-L4 The OP's function doesn't seem async either

Comment: @RobertMonfera no it does not make it async per se. But it's the reason why people use redux-thunx: to make async calls. When the async operation completes you can `dispatch` again to updatethe state (ie `{type:FETCH_COMPLETE}`)

Comment: @Sylvain yes it's a frequent reason, but not "the" reason - there's plenty of synchronous use of redux-thunk. As the OP's action creator (and reducer, of course) are synchronous, it's wrong to say "your action creator is in the form of an async action creator", therefore it can't be the explanation. Could be reworded with no loss to your intent as "IF your action creator is in the form of an async action creator (as it often is, though your code example is synchronous), THEN you MAY get this behavior" - it's OK to answer a question different from the one being presented as long as it's clear.